# WordPress Conditional Tags For Pagination Pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, conditional-statements

I am working with [WordPress Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and want something different that is not common. Currently I am using below codes on `index.php` of a [WordPress Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) that is juts covering 66% of my desire that I shared below.

```
<?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()):?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On First Page Only Like www.example.com -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On All Pages Except First Only Like www.example.com/page/2/, www.example.com/page/3/, www.example.com/page/4/, www.example.com/page/5/ ....  -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I want to show different data on main page and also on `www.example.com/page/2/` as something below...

```
<?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()):?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On First Page Only Like www.example.com -->
<?php elseif( conditional goes here ) ?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On Second Page Only Like www.example.com/page/2/ -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On All Pages Except First And Second Only Like www.example.com/page/3/, www.example.com/page/4/, www.example.com/page/5/ ....  -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

So Is this possible and if yes then what code should be use instead of `conditional goes here`?

Comment: I don't understand your question :S Do you want the same data appearing on main page and second page or?

Comment: @dingo_d Question Edited: I want different data everywhere as mentioned in the question. I want to use different data on first page, second page and all the rest pages...

Answer (score 0):

So basically you just want this

```
<?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()):?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On First Page Only Like www.example.com -->
<?php elseif( conditional goes here ) ?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On Second Page Only Like www.example.com/page/2/ -->
<?php elseif( conditional goes here ) ?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On Second Page Only Like www.example.com/page/3/ -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- Different Data Will Be Shown On All Pages Except First Only Like www.example.com/page/4/, www.example.com/page/5/, www.example.com/page/6/ ....  -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is this what you meant?

EDIT:

To answer what you'd need to add in the conditional.

Well you'd have to add a check if it's a specific page with `is_page()`, but you'd need to have id's of that pages first. This is not a broad function that you can implement on any theme and will work because you are targeting your pages. The pages you create are specific.

Say you create a page that is called About us. That page will have some id assigned to it, which you can check by going on the pages menu in wp, and then hovering over pages link, and looking down on the url that pops up in the lower left side of your browser. It will have the format like:

`www.example.com/theme/wp-admin/post.php?post=1234&action=edit`

the 1234 is the id of that page. So you'd have to first check page id, then add that to conditional. But as I said, if you delete that page, and want another page in its place, you'd have to change the conditional accordingly. It won't automatically recognize what you want...

Comment: Yes, This is what I want. So what to add instead of `conditional goes here`?

Comment: I know it but I am asking about `index.php` page where there are many posts having excerpt only so its mean that there will be many posts on a page so what to add in `is_page()` and also when I will publish a new post then how it will update the code automatically...???

Comment: I totally didn't understand you :S You mean you want pagination to appear so you have, for example, only 5 posts on the first page, and then that you can go to second page with other 5 posts etc.?

Comment: I Want Different Data On First Page Only Like www.example.com, Then Different Data  On Second Page Only Like www.example.com/page/2/, Then Different Data On All Rest Pages Except First And Second Only Like www.example.com/page/3/, www.example.com/page/4/, www.example.com/page/5/ ....

Comment: Well then create different posts (or pages) with different content on them. If you want it to be paged like posts, create a page that displays posts, and then in Reading options choose to see only 1 post per page.

Comment: I am working on `index.php` only and I don't want to make new pages. Well anyway thanks for your help. I am trying to find out any solution then will share here also.

Comment: I really don't see the problem here, you can work only in index.php, you just need to set the options like I told you. In your theme options, set the first page to blog post, then in reading just set in the `Settings -> Reading` the `Blog pages show at most` to 1, and set up pagination :\

Comment: I am designing my own template so its from basic. I want different different data in first page, second page then all rest page. `Settings -> Reading` will effect on all pages that I don't want...

Comment: Well sorry I can't help you :\

Comment: Anyway thanks for sharing your vies till now. I am trying and will share here when I will get it...